# LINQ query not working properly

Tags: visual-studio-2010, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

**LINQ query not working properly**

I want to do as following, I want to access the visitor records from visitor table on certain conditions

I want to get list of last 5 distinct visitor which have visited the place

I am using the follwing query to get the result, but when it comes to distinct() it causes the problem, distinct() destroys the existing order.

```
var result = ObjPlace.visitorlist
.where(visitpalce => visitplace.name == Placename)
.OrderByDescending(visitor => visitor.visitdate)
.Select(x => x.visitorID)
.Distinct()
.take(5);
```

when i removes distinct() it works perfectly...

how can I achieve the same?

Comment: Can you run a SQL trace and see what SQL statements are being passed to the server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 var query = from v in ObjPlace.visitorlist
             where v.name == Placename
             group v by v.visitorID into g
             let lastVisit = g.Max(x => x.visitdate)
             orderby lastVisit descending
             select g.First(v => v.visitdate == lastVisit);
```

This will return distinct list of entities oredered by last visit. Then just take top five of them:

```
query.Take(5)
```

You need grouping here, because one visitor could have several visits in top 5 records. So, first you are filtering your list by placename. Then group all visits by visitor. I.e. you have groups of visits. In each group you define last visit time of visitor, and then just select first visit entity in group, which has time equal to last visitdate of that visitor.

Comment: Just wondering, do you need `orderby lastVisit descending` since you have let lastVisit  ?

Answer (score 0):

You might try changing the order:

```
var result = ObjPlace.visitorlist
               .Where(visitpalce => visitplace.name == Placename)
               .Distinct()
               .OrderByDescending(visitor => visitor.visitdate)
               .Select(x => x.visitorID)
               .Take(5);
```

Comment: it dosen't give me distinct data :(

Answer (score 0):

What is the distinct data that you are trying to get ?

If your object implements IEquatable then all the fields will be compared - i.e. if the dates are different in two objects they will be distinct, but also if any other fields are different the objects will be considered different.

Can you post a sample of your input data, the output you get and the expected output ?